# Using type select on only one column with NSTableView in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm working in XCode 9.3, Swift developing an application for MacOS.

I've created a table that currently has two columns. I want to use type select that only acts on one column so that when the user types the first few letters, it only selects within the first column and not in the 2nd column.

The Apple documentation has an example in Objective-C here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/RowSelection/RowSelection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH6-SW1
but I can't seem to translate that into Swift. I've included the table code below. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource {
  func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return directoryItems?.count ?? 0
  }

  // Sorting.
  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) {
    guard let sortDescriptor = tableView.sortDescriptors.first else {
      return
    }

    if let order = Directory.FileOrder(rawValue: sortDescriptor.key!) {
      sortOrder = order
      sortAscending = sortDescriptor.ascending
      reloadFileList()
    }
  }

}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {

  fileprivate enum CellIdentifiers {
    static let NameCell = "NameCellID"
    static let TimeCell = "TimeCellID"
    static let SizeCell = "SizeCellID"
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    var image: NSImage?
    var text: String = ""
    var cellIdentifier: String = ""

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long

    guard let item = directoryItems?[row] else {
      return nil
    }

    if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0] {
      image = item.icon
      text = item.name
      cellIdentifier = CellIdentifiers.NameCell

    } else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[1] {
      let asset = AVAsset(url: item.url as URL)
      let audioTime = asset.duration
      text = audioTime.durationText
      cellIdentifier = CellIdentifiers.TimeCell

    } else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[2] {
      text = item.isFolder ? "--" : sizeFormatter.string(fromByteCount: item.size)
      cellIdentifier = CellIdentifiers.SizeCell
    }

    if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: cellIdentifier), owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
      cell.textField?.stringValue = text
      cell.imageView?.image = image ?? nil
      return cell
    }

    return nil
  }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how does what it did differ from what you want?

Comment: I've tried: 
`func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,shouldTypeSelectFor event: NSEvent,withCurrentSearch searchString: String?) -> Bool
  {
    return true
  }` 
If I change return to false, type select doesn't work anywhere. I've tried adding if statements but I can't seem to pull in the name of the columns or cells. They all come back 'nil'. I'm not totally sure I've tried that function in the right place or if it's the right function to start with at all. I can capture the search string in an optional with it but that's about it.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `shouldTypeSelectFor:etc:etc:` method in which you tried to get the names of the columns? I can probably help with this, but I need to see what you've tried so far to see what went wrong.

Comment: I've tried putting this in the NSTableViewDelegate;
`func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView,shouldTypeSelectFor event: NSEvent,withCurrentSearch searchString: String?) -> Bool
  {
    if tableView.cell?.title == "NameCellID" {
      print(String(describing: tableView.cell?.title))
      return true
    }
      else {
        print(String(describing: tableView.cell?.title))
        return false
      }
    }`
tableView.cell?.title just shows up as nil. I wish I had a better understanding of this, but I just do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is twofold:

First, you need to set an Identifier for each of your table columns. You can do this by selecting the column in Interface Builder, going to the Identity Inspector, and setting it to some string value:

[image]

Once you've done that, create some static properties to refer to these identifiers (this isn't *strictly* necessary, since you could of course just use `rawValue` to do a plain string comparison the Objective-C way, but the new Swift 4 identifiers are type-safe, and thus preferred). Do that like this:

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {
    private struct TableColumns {
        static let foo = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("Foo")
        static let bar = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("Bar")
    }

    ...

}
```

Now, you can use these identifiers to refer to your columns, using `tableColumn(withIdentifier:)` (or `column(withIdentifier:)` if you just want the column number). I recommend doing this everywhere you refer to them, including in your `tableView(:viewFor:row:)` method, since the way you're doing it now with `tableView.tableColumns[0]` and so forth depends on the order of the columns, and if the user reorders them, it may cause unexpected behavior. Using the identifier will make sure you're always looking at the column you think you're looking at.

Anyway, once you've got your identifiers set up, you can address the second problem: You're using the wrong delegate method. Instead of `tableView(:shouldTypeSelectFor:searchString:)`, which is meant for catching these things at the event level (i.e., the user just pressed a key. Should I invoke the type select system at all?), use `tableView(:typeSelectStringFor:row:)`. This method lets you return the string given to the type selection mechanism for each row/column combination in your table. For the ones you want type-select to ignore, just return `nil`; otherwise, return the string that you'd expect to have to type to select that particular row. So, something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, typeSelectStringFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> String? {
    if tableColumn?.identifier == TableColumns.foo {
        return directoryItems?[row].name
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Thank you so much. I still have a lot to learn about tables. Your explanation was so clear and thorough. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @RickshawBoy My pleasure. In the future, please be sure to include the code you've already tried in your question. It makes it much easier to figure out what you're trying to do, and how to help.